# Confirm Delete Without onClick Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

I'm trying to create confirmation boxes after clicking to "Delete This" links.

I can do this with the use of `onClick` event. However, I read that this is not cool. So, I found a cool library to make confirmation boxes for me. It's called Bootbox, but I guess that does not matter.

This is what I did (pasted, actually):

I got a link like this:

```
<a class="confirm" href=#>Delete Record|</a>
```

This is the javascript code to handle clicking events for this anchor:

```
$(document).on("click", ".confirm", function(e) {
  bootbox.confirm("?", function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }); 
});
```

I can get the user input like this. However, I don't know how to let user go to delete page if he/she clicked on Yes, or do nothing when he/she clicked No.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I am curious where you read about it not being cool ahaha.

Comment: @Kuma `confirm()` prompts are synchronous (block the rest of the app) and are not customizable...

Comment: is onClick asp.net one or just a typo ?

Comment: Here's how I'd set it up: http://jsfiddle.net/ks9fF/ - note the `href` being set and the `window.location.href` (which does the redirect)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : (first was off topic)

You must redirect the href of your link in callback result only result is true so

```
<a href="/Page/Delete/2" class="confirm">Delete</a>


$(document).on("click", "a.confirm", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(e.target);
    bootbox.confirm("?", function (result) {
        if (result) {
            window.location.href = $(target)[0].href;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this what you understood from the question? I want user to go to mypage.com/delete/12, if he/she clicks to "Delete 12", and do nothing if clicked No.

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville Where do you store this "/delete/12" URI? The `href` you posted shows "#"

Comment: Sorry i read too fast the question. I will edit my response. You must call your request in confirm callback function

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you store data, you want to delete. If you just want to hide deleted element from page, you can do that with javascript.
eg.:

```
$(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
bootbox.confirm("?", function(result) {
$(this).hide(200); // animated
 }); 
});
```

If you store data you show in database, you should use ajax to request for example php that erase data from database.